# sending D2C message to a specific Consumer Group in Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Is there a way to send a D2C message to a specific Consumer Group instead of Default Consumer group in Azure IoT Hub?

Comment: have a look at the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features

Answer (score 2):

Message to the Event Hub endpoint are always delivered to all consumer groups. The same is true for the actual Event Hub.

But it sounds like you want to take a look at message routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-custom
Routing allows you to filter messages and/or send them to specifc endpoints. If you need more than one Event Hub endpoint, apart from the built-in one, add Event Hubs as custom endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-custom